# Is my understanding of Java's Class and Type correct?

Tags: java, class, types

In Java, when you define a class, you are defining a type implicitly. Say, I defined a class `User`:

```
class User {}
```

Then we get a class `User` and an implicit type `User`.

When we use the name `User`, sometimes we are referencing `class User`, sometimes `type User`. Let me give some examples:

```
User user = new User();
^^^^(1)         ^^^^(2)

public void saveUser(User user) {
                     ^^^^(3)
}

class Dao<T> {
    def save(T t) {}
}

new Dao<User>();
        ^^^^(4)

Class cls = User.class;
            ^^^^(5)

User user = (User) someObj;
             ^^^^(6)
```

My understandings:

1. Position `(1)` is `type User`
2. Position `(2)` is the constructor of `class User`
3. Position `(3)` is `type User`
4. Position `(4)` is `type User`
5. Position `(5)` is `class User`
6. Position `(6)` is `type User`

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Is there really a need to differentiate? A class is always a type

Comment: I found it difficult to understand `subclassing`, `subtyping`, or scala's type system if I can't figure out that is there any difference between `class` and `type`, and what it is if there is.

Comment: @Freewind why are you suddenly talking about Scala?

Comment: If you have `User myVar = new User();` then your variable `myVar` **is of the type User** and at the same time you can say `myVar` then points to an **Object of the class User**.. But I think there is no need to break your head over it :)

Comment: An instance can be thought of like a snapshot of class at any moment. So whenever you see new (), we are talking about the instance. Just a thought

Comment: @Giovanni Botta, sorry to mention scala here. Just because I found its type-system is hard to learn, and think better understanding the concepts of Java first since it's a little easier. Then I have these questions.

Comment: @Freewind oh no need to apologize. The two type systems are quite different although Scala is built on the JVM so it has some of the same limitations as Java. IMO start with the language you want to learn because understanding the java type system won't necessarily help you understand the scala one.

Comment: @Freewind there are many resources out there, you can find an interesting video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ptCvn4-lyXM).

Answer (score 3):

I would say:

```
Class cls = User.class;
            ^^^^^^^^^^(5)

User user = new User();
            ^^^^^^^^^^(7)
```

1. This is the type of a Declaration of a variable of type `User`
2. This is the type of a Definition of a variable of type `User` (not the constructor, the constructor may exists only i a subclass of User)
3. This is the type of a Declaration of a parameter/argument of type `User`
4. This is the generic type `User` of a definition of a generic default constructor of type `Dao`
5. This is a referention to the class of the type `User`.
6. This is a Cast to the type `User`.
7. This is a call of the default-constructor of the Type/Class `User`.

Type or Class? Every Class can be a type, not every type can be a Class. Primitives like `int` for example, is a type but not a Class. If you are perfect-scientific-correct, you must specify that `User` is a Class. If you say `User` is a type, its not wrong but also not specific.

Comment: I am so happy that he did not ask if `void` is a type. I have no idea! Maybe `void` must be a type because the JLS sais it can be the return-type of a canonical method declaration.

Comment: actually, I found it `Note
the void indicating that the method does not actually return a result; void is not a type, it
is an annotation on the method.` on this link: http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/riccardo/courses/csu370-fa07/lect4.pdf

Answer (score 1):

- in (1), `User` is the type, `user` a reference to an object of that type;
- in (2) the expression `new User()` creates a new instance of type `User`; that instance gets assigned to the reference `user`;
- in (3) you are passing to function `saveUser` a reference to an object of type `User`;
- in (4) `User` is a type parameter, that is, it specifies which object type the `Dao` class is parameterized by;
- in (5) you are obtaining a reference to an object of type `Class<User>`, which represent the type `User`, it **is technically not** *the* `User` type;
- in (6) you are adding an explicit type casting, telling the compiler that the reference `someObj` is of type `User` and assigning the value of that reference to the reference `user` (which has type `User`); depending on the type of `someObj` the cast might or not be required by the compiler and might or might not cause a `ClassCastException`.

Answer (score 0):

`Position (2)` represents the *object* itself instantiated by calling the `constructor` with no arguments.

All other assumptions are right.

Answer (score 0):

A class is an example of abstract data type.
So, a class IS a type and you can indifferently name User "class" or "type".

Mind that the opposite is not always true, so a type is not necessarily a class (for example primitive types like int float,ecc. )

Comment: Look at his list at the bottom of the question.